# Jenkins 1.510 deletes all CVS branch checkout files

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins, 1.510.

It working well with all CVS checkout from head.

However if I use checkout from branch, it checks out all files successfully shows the message as successfully checked out. But the checkouted directory contains nothing. When I checked the files while the build is in progress the files are copied to directory however at end of build all the files are getting deleted.

Can you please help me?

Comment: What version is your CVS plugin?

Comment: I am using Jenkins CVS Plug-in 2.8 https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CVS+Plugin